# Jenkins update available notification

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I am not able to see   jenkins update available notification when  I  go to manage system but I see there is latest 1.439 in (http://jenkins-ci.org/) and am in 1.432, even if I copy 1.439 war file into tomcat, I am not seeing any version update in UI even after restart? Any idea why it is happening like this?

Thanks
Sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason why you do not see update notification could be you are behind a firewall and your jenkins is thus unable to get update information.

As for why jenkins does not update even after placing the 1.439 war into tomcat, it could be due to multiple reasons.

- Is the war named jenkins.war?
- Did you delete the existing jenkins.war?
- For good measure, can you delete the exploded jenkins folder and restart?

Comment: Well, I had figured it out, Yes I deleted the previous exploded war file and restarted again worked fine. Thanks for your input.